# MySQL Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

My query looks like

```
SELECT t2.id, t3.id, t3.sys_modified_date, t3.sys_created_date, 
    t3.email, t3.enabled, t3.password, t3.passwordagain, t4.id, 
    t4.sys_modified_date, t4.sys_created_date, t4.job, t4.name, 
    t4.surname, t3.retrivalHash, t3.username 
FROM Customer_Contractor t0 INNER JOIN Contractor t1 ON t0.contractor = 
    t1.id INNER JOIN User t3 ON t2.id = t3.partyId LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Profile t4 ON t3.profileId = t4.id, Party t2 
WHERE t0.customer = ? 
ORDER BY t2.id ASC
```

I'm getting error:

> Unknown column 't2.id' in 'on clause'

I don't know what is wrong, please help me with this.

Comment: `Party t2` is outside the scope of the `ON` clause. You'll need to refactor it into the `FROM` instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your query, `Party t2` is not in the same scope as the rest of the ANSI-92 joined tables - which is why `INNER JOIN User t3 ON t2.id = t3.partyId` fails.

I suspect you want something like:

```
SELECT t2.id, t3.id, t3.sys_modified_date, t3.sys_created_date, 
    t3.email, t3.enabled, t3.password, t3.passwordagain, t4.id, 
    t4.sys_modified_date, t4.sys_created_date, t4.job, t4.name, 
    t4.surname, t3.retrivalHash, t3.username 
FROM Customer_Contractor t0 
INNER JOIN Contractor t1 ON t0.contractor = t1.id 
INNER JOIN Party t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN User t3 ON t2.id = t3.partyId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Profile t4 ON t3.profileId = t4.id
WHERE t0.customer = ? 
ORDER BY t2.id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct. There is no table with an alias `t2` when the alias is first used

You are doing this

```
Customer_Contractor t0
INNER JOIN
Contractor t1 ON t0.contractor = t1.id
INNER JOIN
User t3 ON t2.id = t3.partyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Profile t4 ON t3.profileId = t4.id
CROSS JOIN
Party t2
```

When I suspect you want this (really? A cross join?)

```
Customer_Contractor t0
INNER JOIN
Contractor t1 ON t0.contractor = t1.id
CROSS JOIN
Party t2 
INNER JOIN
User t3 ON t2.id = t3.partyId
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Profile t4 ON t3.profileId = t4.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly join onto the Party table (aliased as t2). Without this JOIN, the on condition is meaningless.

Without knowing the structure of your tables, it's hard to know how you can explicitly join onto Party.

Answer (score 1):

An `ON` clause can only ‘see’ table aliases that are defined to the left of that `ON` clause within the same table reference group, in other words, within the same group of joins.

The `t2` alias is neither to the left of the particular `ON` clause that references it, nor even in the same table reference group. (Distinct groups are separated with commas.)

The `WHERE` clause is the only place where you can reference all the aliases, defined in all table reference groups. But if I were you, I would replace that comma join with an appropriate explicit join.

Reference:

- [JOIN Syntax (MySQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)